# Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Sync.MobileServicePushStatus.CancelledByAuthenticationError

Tags: android, .net, authentication, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have created a mobile service in Azure. Everything was working fine until I added Authentication to my App. The Authentication seems to be working fine as I have added authentication with Azure active directory and another one with Google. Both authentications let me sign in and also give me the userid. but I get the following error while I try to add new entry.

```
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Sync.MobileServicePushStatus.CancelledByAuthenticationError
```

Also, If I try to add the item from the Web app, it signs me in with the application key, but when I try to Post anything it gives me a prompt for sign in again and doesnot sign me in with the same credentials.

Iam following this tutorial https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-xamarin-android-get-started-users/

Comment: Is everything in the tutorial working fine for you? 

It looks like Push is breaking - do you have push integrated in your application? What do you mean by adding the item from the Web App? Are you using a JavaScript backend?